# Do I have to migrate if I change variables type - realm?

Tags: android, realm

At first I had

```
    @SerialName("state") var state: String
```

Then I decided to do this - changed the type

```
    @SerialName("state") @BooleanString var state: Int
```

Do I've to do something additional in migration or am I good to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change of property's name, type or constraints requests a migration.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

Multiple cases:

- you need to migrate to keep previous database and data : create a class implementing `RealmMigration` and migrate what needs to
- you don't need to migrate because you don't care : `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded`
- you don't need to migrate because it's a fresh install : do nothing